# I'm asking when I reset Jquery form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery form.reset when clicking the reset button event,
The readonly part is also initialized and the value value disappears.
When data is loaded, the name and memo values ​​are set,
and the memo values ​​remain the same even when the reset button event occurs.
How can I keep data when reset event occurs?

```js
// reset button event
$("#reset").on("click", function(){
   var form = document.getElementById("SettingForm");
   form.reset();
});

// ajax data load
success : function(data) {

    $("#name").val(data.name);

    $("#memo").text(data.memo);

}    

<form id="SettingForm" action="" method="POST">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="panelW">
<tr>
     <th class="w35p">name</th>
     <td><input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" readonly/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <th class="w35p"><c th:text="#{configure.memo}">memo</c></th>
     <td><textarea id="memo" name="memo" value=""  readonly></textarea> 
     </td>
 </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where it's important to distinguish between attributes and properties.

The `value` *property* is the current value of the input, which will be submitted in the form.

The value *attribute* is the input's initial default value. It's copied into the property when it's initially rendered, and again when `form.reset()` is used.

So if you want to update the default value, you need to assign the attribute; `.val()` just assigns the property.

Similarly, for a `textarea`, the text is used as the default when the form is reset.

```
success : function(data) {
    $("#name").val(data.name).attr(data.name);
    $("#memo").val(data.memo).text(data.memo);
}
```

```js
const data = {
  name: "Default name",
  memo: "Default memo"
};

$("#name").val(data.name).attr("value", data.name);
$("#memo").val(data.memo).text(data.memo);

$("#reset").on("click", function(){
   var form = document.getElementById("SettingForm");
   form.reset();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="SettingForm" action="" method="POST">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="panelW">
    <tr>
      <th class="w35p">name</th>
      <td><input id="name" name="name" type="text" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="w35p">
        <c th:text="#{configure.memo}">memo</c>
      </th>
      <td><textarea id="memo" name="memo" value=""></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: I tried to modify the code as you informed me, but disappears when I click the reset button.

Comment: I forgot an argument to `.attr()`. I tested it in the above snippet.

Comment: Can i ask one more? not working  $("#memo").val(data.memo).text(data.memo);
in IE..